# Data design issue. Need help with normalization

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

I am developing one web based payment system. I am facing problem in database design.

Following are tables and their fields:

```
Customer: cust_id    , name   
Supplier: supplier_id, name   
Employee: employee_id, name   
Expanse:  expanse_id , name

group: group_id, group_name   
(groups are: {1,Customer},{2,Supplier},{3,Employee},{4,Expanse})
```

and there will be one more table:

```
payment: payment_id, group_id, name(ids), amount
```

In above table, name field will contain id of respective group. Like if group id is 1 and name is 15 that is customer whose id is 15 (customer_id=15)

I want to know that above tables satisfy 3NF? if not then what is the correct way.

Also i want to know that if i want list of all the payment, which will have fields like: payment_id, group_name, name_of_person/expanse. What will be the query to get this list.

Comment: Not 3NF to me.   That would be some ugly queries.

Comment: "In above table, name field will contain id of respective group. Like if group id is 1 and name is 15 that is customer whose id is 15 (customer_id=15)" -- This is too cryptic.  Please show sample data, and show the query.

Comment: Customer table data ({1,'Ana'},{2,'John'},...,{15,'Tim'}). Supplier table data ({1,'Mark'},{2,'Sophia'},...,{18,'Elizabeth'}). payment table data ({1,1,15},{4,2,18}). Then list of payment should be: ({1,'Customer','Tim'},{4,'Supplier','Elizabeth})

Comment: What are the FDs?  Without that, questions about normalization are mere speculation.

Answer (score 0):

One of these is not like the others - expanse

Entities:
groupID, ID, name

composite PK on groupID, ID

Answer (score 0):

(As non-native English speaker, "expanse" is not immediately clear to me)

I'd join the four tables (customer, supplier, employee, expanse) to a single table

```
(id, group, name)
```

Depending on your needs, `id` could be unique key, so `group` would be only foreign key for linking group. In this case `group` can be dropped from `payment`.

Comment: It's likely a typo of "expense".